# EF Core 7.0.4 How to get all parents of an object Blazor Server

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I am trying to get all of the parents associated with an object. Some objects will have parents whereas other may not. I'm using this data to create a breadcrumb.

### Folder.cs

```
    {
        public Folder()
        {
            Children = new List<Folder>();
            Files = new List<File>();
            FolderUserNotifications = new List<FolderUserNotification>();
        }
        public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
        public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[^\\\./:\*\?\""<>\|]{1}[^\\/:\*\?\""<>\|]{0,254}$", ErrorMessage = @"The following special characters are not allowed: \ / * :  ?  "" < > | """)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public virtual Folder Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Folder> Children { get; set; }
        public virtual List<File> Files { get; set; }
        public virtual List<FolderUserNotification> FolderUserNotifications { get; set; }
       
    }
```

### FolderService.cs

```
        public async Task<Folder> GetFolderFileListByClientIdParentId(Guid clientId, Guid folderId)
        {
            using dbContext db = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
            {
                Folder result = await db.Folders.Where(y => y.Id == folderId)
                                      .Include(x => x.Children)
                                      .ThenInclude(i => i.Files)
                                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                return result;
            }
        }
        public Folder GetFoldersParentIds(Guid folderId) 
        {
            using dbContext db = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
            {
                
                Folder folderWithParents = db.Folders.Where(i => i.Id == folderId).Include(i => i.Parent).ThenInclude(i => i.Parent).FirstOrDefault();
                return folderWithParents;
            }
        }
```

GetFolderFileListByClientIdParentId is a call that im using elsewhere in my code. It brings back all of the children and I'm able to do all the operations I need to do on it. GetFoldersParentIds is the one that I'm having troubles with. If I keep adding .include(i=> i.Parent) it will continue getting all of the parents. The one in the code now gets the Folder its in its parent and its parent because of the two includes. How can I get all of them without having to put 100 .includes?

Comment: You are using a so-called adjacency list. To work with it, you need to use recursive queries using CTE. However, Entity Framework does not have such a built-in capability. Therefore, either raw SQL will have to be used, or take the [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) library. And use [Common Table Expression](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HierarchyId is a common solution to issues like this. SQL Server and EF Core 8 have full support for this type, though you can use it with earlier versions AFAIK, just not query against it as nicely.

With EF Core 8 you can use `.IsDecendantOf` to get a specific item and all ancestors. A good example of this is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew  under "Get all ancestors of an entity"

If your DBMS does not support something similar then worst case you can implement your own computed equivalent. I'd often used a simple pipe-delimited string so a value like 1|16|22|48 when I read record #116, this gives me the hierarchy I can fetch the rest of the chain with a 2nd `IN` call. With EF Core 8 and SQL server you can fetch the entire set in 1 call, so a bit more efficient.

So for instance if you have a particular itemId:

```
var hierarchyString = _context.Items
    .Where(x => x.Id == itemId)
    .Select(x => x.Hierarchy)
    .Single();
var itemIds = hierarchyString.Split('|', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
itemIds.Add(itemId);
var items = _context.Items
    .Where(x => itemIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .ToList();
var item = items.First(x => x.Id == itemId);
```

This runs a first query to just get the hierarchy string from the desired item.  We extract the IDs then fetch those IDs for the entire hierarchy into memory. EF will be tracking each of these instances, so when it builds the entities it will resolve the parent references from the tracked items it has read, so "item" .Parent.Parent.Parent should resolve its way back up the chain.

If you want to eager load other information about the item in question, then you would likely need to take a slightly different approach as you wouldn't want to necessarily `Include` all of those additional details across all Parent items. (Adding the `.Include`s to the `.ToList` call in the example above, though that is one option)  If we just want to eager load other related references for the particular item of interest:

```
var item = _context.Items
    .Include(x => x.OtherDetail)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.OtherOtherDetail)
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .Single(x => x.Id == itemId);

var itemIds = item.Hierarchy.Split('|', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x));
_context.Items
    .Where(x => itemIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Here we load just our single item with it's eager-loaded relations other than the Parent. (Including Parent shouldn't cause any issue, but isn't a necessary inclusion) We do the same hierarchy split to fetch the entire hierarchy, but in this case we just need EF to load the entities into its tracking cache so we don't bother capturing the result of the `ToList()`. Now when we go to Item.Parent and .Parent.Parent the lazy loading proxy will get the references from the tracking cache.

You can inspect the behavior by hooking a profiler up to the database to check that it isn't firing off any lazy loading queries when accessing the parent references once all parents in the hierarchy have been loaded. This does make use of lazy loading proxies though (which I enable by default as a safety net vs. getting null reference exceptions)

Manually managing something like a Hierarchy is fairly simple. The challenge is handling cases where items can be moved around within a hierarchy and ensuring that all descendants are updated, and testing those scenarios to ensure your hierarchy doesn't get out of sync. Moving items around can essentially be done with a string search and string replace. Writing a hierarchy for a new item involves just taking the hierarchy of it's parent and appending the parent's ID.

Answer (score 2):

As to my knowledge you can't do that with LINQ alone.

You have the following options

1. Use [HierarchyId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver16) or the corresponding data type if you are not using SQL Server. Then you can use the EF option to call an SQL function to get the whole hierarchy
2. Pull everything in memory, order it in advance and cache it. Might not be good option for folders but often works for things like categories and subcategories. Obviously how feasible this is depends on how many items you have
3. Create an SQL View or write query in source that uses [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (or the corresponding feature if you are using database different from SQL Server) then map it to a class and execute the query that way
4. You have the option to recursively issue more queries. If your hierarchy is shallow that might work. You'll need to gather the ids from the next level before issuing a single query using those ids to reduce the number of queries. Still you'll have as many queries as the depth of the hierarchy which does not sound very good

It looks to me that HierarchyId is the best for your case but can't be certain

Answer (score 0):

Someone on my team was able to solve this problem by doing this.

```
                var folderList = db.Folders.Where(i => i.ClientId ==clientId).ToList();
                Folder folderWithParents = folderList.Where(i => i.Id == folderId && i.ParentId != null).FirstOrDefault();
                if (folderWithParents == null) 
                {
                    folderWithParents = db.Folders.Where(i => i.Id == folderId).Include(i => i.Parent).ThenInclude(i => i.Parent).FirstOrDefault();
                    return folderWithParents;
                }
                else
                {
                    return folderWithParents;
                }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. First of all it only gets the parents of one folder due to that FirstOrDefault, second it only seems to go 3 levels deep

Comment: I have no clue why it works but I tested it down to 30 deep and it brings back all of the parents

Comment: what is this clientId? Do all folders in a hierarchy belong to the same clientId?

Comment: @Stilgar yes all folders in a hierarchy belong  to one clientId

Comment: It seems like in this case you are just loading the full hierarchy anyway, you don't even need the second query, you can order the tree in C# code. My hypothesis is that because the entities are loaded and tracked EF kicks off a feature to automatically assign related entities if they are already loaded in the context. That code is very easy to break, throw in AsNoTracking() on the first query and see what happens. Also reordering of queries can cause it to stop working. If you leave it like this you'd better add comments about how it works